# Report Builder remove expand/collapse action

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a table in Report Builder, is it not possible at all to remove the expand/collapse functionality from it? 
I would also like to open the wizard and revisit the steps which were executed to create the table. Is that possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Is it possible to remove the expand/collapse functionality from the tablix?** 
   I'm not sure what you're talking about, but if it is the grey border at the left and top of the tablix then I don't think it's possible. It's what is useful in this kind of data region.
2. **Is it possible to reopen the wizard to revisit the steps for creating a tablix?** 
   I don't think so. 
   First step: choose a dataset. 
   Second step: choose the fields. You can modify all this when the tablix is already created by creating rows and colums when you right click on the tablix. 
   Third step : choose a total. You can do so by clicking on a line group at the bottom of the screen and selecting 'add a total' and then 'before' or 'after'.
   Fourth step : for the style, you can only click on a cell and select a background color.

   So, except the dataset, you can modify everything that's in the wizard but at different places.

Answer (score 4):

You can remove the expand / collapse functionality, or the toggle, from the report. If you open and edit the .rdl file as XML, you can remove the `<Visibility>` node from the `<TablixMember>`.

For example this:

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group Name="Details" />
  <Visibility>
    <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    <ToggleItem>Action</ToggleItem>
  </Visibility>
</TablixMember>
```

would become this:

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group Name="Details" />
</TablixMember>
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done via the RDL as described above or it can also be done in the Report Builder.  Assuming it's a Row Group that has the Expand/Collapse option you want to remove, in the Row Groups section of the Report Builder, right-click on the Row-Group Name and select "Group Properties".  Select "Visibility" in the left nav menu.  Uncheck the "Display can be toggled by this report item:" option.  You'll also likely need to change the option above, "When the report is initially run" to "Show".  Then hit the OK button.  Then run your report to see that the Expand/Collapse option has been removed.

-Eric Isaacs